# Adding an optional free keyword argument to a custom robotframework java library keyword

Tags: robotframework

I am attempting to create a keyword in a java library that is equivalent to the following python library keyword:

```
def findObjectFoo(String targetClass, String targetName = None, String targetText = None)
```

targetClass is always required. targetName and targetText are optional. targetText can be provided without providing targetName.

When using overloading I can create a function with one string or two strings but I can't differentiate between `findObjectFoo(targetClass, targetName)` and `findObjectFoo(targetClass,targetText)`

How would this be implemented in a robotframework java library?

Comment: You just said "targetText can be provided without providing targetName." from what follows when targetName is given targetText **must** also be provided, which is trivial with the normal method overloading. But in the same time, you are citing calls where it's only targetName, or only targetText passed; as the method signatures are probably the same (`(String, String)`, I presume?) there's no way for the compiler to know which one you intent to call. Though for this case python is easier, you still have to specify which of the two you are passing - e.g. `findObjectFoo(class, targetText=txt)`

Comment: In Java, you could use `java.util.Map` as the last method parameter; the you can pass key:value pairs, and fall back to defaults if one of the optional is not defined.